# How to pass env variables to ClojureScript app?

Tags: clojurescript

I have a ClojureScript app that is launched from Leiningen. How do I pass env variables to the app when it starts (could be when it buids)

Comment: Can you describe the use-case for this? Since ClojureScript runs in the browser, it is different than a server process that may want to access env vars.

Comment: I need to pass current git branch configuration to the frontend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two **build time** options:

### Using macros

CLJS macros are Clojure code, that runs at compile time.  So you can use
regular Clojure code to read the environment variables and either
include them or do other macro-iy things.

### Using `goog.define`

CLJS integrates with this facility of the Google Closure compiler to
pass build time
[configurations](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#closure-defines).

#### Example using both

Relative minimal `project.clj`, that sets a `goog.define` from
env-var `E1`:

```clj
; project.clj
(defproject envvars "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :min-lein-version "2.9.1"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.597"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]]
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              [{:id "dev"
                :source-paths ["src"]
                :compiler {:closure-defines {envvars.core.e1 ~(System/getenv "E1")} ; XXX
                           :main envvars.core
                           :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                           :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/envvars.js"
                           :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                           :source-map-timestamp true}}]})
```

Macro, that reads the env-var `E2`:

```clj
; src/envvars/coremacros.clj 
(ns envvars.coremacros)

(defmacro load-via-macro []
  (System/getenv "E2")) ; XXX
```

Example "main", to print the content:

```clj
; src/envvars/core.cljs 
(ns envvars.core
    (:require-macros [envvars.coremacros]))

(enable-console-print!)

(goog-define e1 "undefined") ; XXX

(def e2 (envvars.coremacros/load-via-macro)) ; XXX

(println e1 e2) ; XXX
```

Build with:

```
E1=E1 E2=E2 lein cljsbuild once
```

Behold the `E1 E2` being printed in the console

Comment: Hi, is there a way to pass the config at runtime too? For instance to pass a company name. And the app shows the company name for instance in a :H1. I could then use the same compiled code for different companies

Answer (score 1):

We can also use an environment handling library such as [env](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/env)

Steps:

- Include a dependency thus:

```
(ns foo
  (:require-macros [adzerk.env :as env]))
```

- Define the var (add `:required` if mandatory)

```
(env/def ENV_VAR :required)
```

- Assuming you're running a shadow-cljs app:

```
export ENV_VAR=<value> && npm install && npx shadow-cljs watch app
```